# Replacing regex match in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am using JavaScript's replace() function to replace a regular expression matching A-Z, a-z, 0-9, dash (-), underscore (_) and dot (.).  I am trying to replace it with part of the matched string with tags around it, but the code I have only replaces the matches with: <b>$1</b>.

Any help, please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<textarea id="demo" rows="10" cols="20">
<table></table>
<b><i>#stock-jsod.20</i>
</b>
</textarea>

<button onclick="testit()">test</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

function testit()
{
var str=document.getElementById("demo").value;
var n = str.replace(/#([A-Za-z0-9_.-]+)/gi, "<b>$0</b>");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=n;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My goal here is to replace #stock-jsod.20 with `<b>#stock-jsod.20</b>`, but currently it only replaces it with `<b>$0</b>`.

Comment: There is already a `<b></b>` around it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Engineer's answer you also don't the `A-Za-z0-9_`. You can just use `\w`. Then you also don't need the case insensitive switch. This is a much simpler regular expression that achieves the same effect:

```
var n = str.replace(/#[\w.-]+/g, "<b>$&</b>");
```

---

Example output:

```
> str = '#abc #def ghi'
"#abc #def ghi"
> str.replace(/#[\w.-]+/g, "<b>$&</b>");
"<b>#abc</b> <b>#def</b> ghi"
```

Comment: @JoshuaShor: What do you mean by "does not work". I've tested it and it appears to work - see the example output. Are you sure that the problem you have is not elsewhere? What is the error you get?

Comment: Yeah, @JoshuaShor has ***strange*** sense of humour !!

Answer (score 2):

Try to use '`$&`' instead of '`$1`'.

More about look -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Description

**UPDATE**: Instead of `document.getElementById("demo").value` you need to use `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML` for getting contents of '`demo`' element.